# Reverse Wordpress 301 Redirect Using Simple Redirection

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I was trying to redirect a link to a google form using a 301 redirect, but I seem to have accidentally redirected the homepage link.

Specifically, I wanted to redirect "munuc.org/registration" to a google form, but somehow along the way I accidentally redirected "munuc.org" to "https://munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/munuc.org/registration".

Can anyone help me fix this? Is there a way to revert to the way it was?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used a plugin to do this ? If so you can uninstall it and try with another one, which i use and works perfectly for 301 redirections, it is named "Redirection" and it has more than 2 million active installations. Then you'll simply need to specify which link do you want to redirect to a new one and that's it !